# What is the rationale/basis for right to rent checks only being required of landlords in England, and not Wales, Scotland or NI?

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, immigration

Landlords in Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland aren’t required by the Immigration Act 2016 to check prospective tenants’ rights to rent as [section 42](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/19/section/42?timeline=false) is still "prospective legislation" and not in force. I’m wondering what the reason our thinking behind this was?

And what other components of the so called hostile environment regime are like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in answer to the first part of the question, this is probably primarily because England, in general, and London, in particular, has the most foreign born people ([35% are in London alone](https://migrationobservatory.ox.ac.uk/resources/briefings/migrants-in-the-uk-an-overview/) and 90% are in England), making it the priority.

[image]

Secondarily, probably because the task of adapting the fine bureaucratic details of a statute or regulation designed for England to the nuances of Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland is a time consuming and detailed technical task that would have delayed enactment of the legislation taking effect anywhere, otherwise, even though it wasn't as high a priority elsewhere, due to lower proportions of immigrants.